# Managing member function execution in C++

Tags: c++, oop, function

I have a class `Managed` that contains a function `f`, which executes other functions of that class.

```
class Managed {
public:
    Managed(){}
    ~Managed(){}

    int f( some arguments ); //managed function
private:
    int A();
    int B();
    int C();
};
```

I want to manage the actions performed by `f` depending on the way the object of class `Managed` was constructed, i.e. making it to behave like this

```
int Managed::f (some arguments) {
    A();
    B();
    A();

    return 0;
}
```

or like this

```
int Managed::f (some arguments) {
    C();
    B();

    return A();
}
```

etc.

I need that management to be very flexible, I need something like scripting the behavior of function `f`. How can I do that in C++?

Comment: Its very unclear. You can not return anything from a `void` function. And what are `some arguments`? do they control how `f` behaves? Can you tell us what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry, corrected the return type.

Comment: How about writing a switch function in `Managed::f(int arg1)`, that does specific job based on it's argument. Based on any type of the object( i.e., residing on stack/heap ), the functionality of the method don't change when called on the instance. So, I amnot sure when you meant , `depending on the way the object of class Managed was constructed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question misses several crucial details (like what `some arguments` are supposed to do).  However, it sounds like maybe you need `Managed` to contain a `std:list` of function pointers.  Then the `f` function can simply walk the list, and call the function specified by each element in turn.

I can't comment on how you might populate the list; that would depend on the API to your class.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

In this particular case you don't need a full blown strategy pattern implementation with interfaces. One function pointer would do:

```
class Managed {
public:
    Managed(int type)
    {
        switch(type) {
        case 1: strategy_ = strategy1; break;
        case 2: strategy_ = strategy2; break;
        default: abort();
        }
    }

    int f(int arg) { return strategy_(this, arg); }

private:
    static int startegy1(Managed* that, int arg)
    {
        that->A();
        that->B();
        that->C();
        return arg;
    }

    static int startegy2(Managed* that, int arg)
    {
        that->A();
        that->C();
        return arg;
    }

    // ... more strategies ...

    int A();
    int B();
    int C();

    int(*strategy_)(Managed*, int arg);
};
```

Comment: forgot to return the int back from f(), but this is my fav by far

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you could use the Command design pattern.   Your f function should take a collection (vector or list) of "commands" (could be simple enumerated integers like Call_A, Call_B, Call_C, Call_A_SaveReturnValue, Call_B_SaveReturnValue, Call_C_SaveReturnValue, ReturnSavedValue, Return0, ReturnInt, etc., or more complicated objects to represent more complicated functionality, then your function f "executes" these commands in order and performs the function for each "command".

Edit: if you wanted the parameters of f() for some other purpose (it wasn't clear in your question), then just set the command line in to the state of the class and use the parameters of f() for whatever you want.

Comment: either that or Strategy pattern

Comment: yes that would work, but the OP wanted something like "scripting" with a lot of flexibility, an I think command is closer to that than strategy.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is very hard to do in c++, because it is a strongly typed language, and that prevents it to be fully flexible like some scripting languages. For example, you will find it difficult to do what you want if you need to pass a variable of a type which is not fixed at the compilation.

If you don't need full full flexibility, and the signature of the method is fixed, then the simplest way is to use pointers to member methods in combination with switch or a lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should try to use inheritance to solve the problem:

```
class Managed
{
public:
    Managed(){}
    ~Managed(){}

    virtual int f(int a,int b,int c);
protected:
    int A() {return 1;}
    int B() {return 2;}
    int C() {return 3;}
};

class Managed1: public Managed
{
    Managed1(){}
    ~Managed1(){}
    virtual int f(int a,int b,int c)
    {
        A();
        B();
        A();
        return 4;
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice, descriptive class names there.